# Testing in node.js with mocha - Newbie

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, testing, mocha.js

I have started implementing TDD in my JS project. I've implemented mocha for that purpose. As these are my first steps what I did:

- Installed node.js
- Installed mocha globally and locally to my project.
- Wrote package.json setting dependencies.
- Wrote makefile.
- Wrote .gitignore to avoid uploading node_modules folder.

Folder structure

project

-- js
----filetotest.js

-- test
---- test.js

What I want to do is to run the command make test in order to run the tests inside test.js that tests the filetotest.js file.
I read about the node.js approach using exports. But is there some way to include the file in the test suite?

I'm stuck here, and I think that my doubt is more about the concept than the tech thing. Will appreciate a lot your help.

To clarify a little bit what I would like to do:
https://nicolas.perriault.net/code/2013/testing-frontend-javascript-code-using-mocha-chai-and-sinon/

I would like to get a similar result through the command line.

Thanks so much,

Guillermo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it right.

Now export your function from **filetotest.js**, like this:

```
var f1 = function(params) {
  // ...
}

exports.f1 = f1
```

In **test.js**, require this file

```
var f1 = require("./filetotest.js").f1

// test f1
```

Btw, if you will put your tests in **/test** directory, mocha will execute them automatically (given that it will be executed from the root of your project)

Comment: Thanks so much! So there is no way to prevent adding the exports... in the original file to test through the command line right?

Comment: implementation itself is hidden, so you have encapsulation. the only exposed part is your function name and parameters, which could be used by another files/modules. using TDD you shall ensure that for given input function provides needed output